# Index pandas series entries with integers

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas Series composed of strings, say something like ["ab", "ac", "bc", "ab", "ab", "abc"], is there a built in function to replace each of the strings by some integer corresponding to the string? In my example, if we index it as "ab" : 0, "ac" : 1, "bc" : 2, "abc" : 3, then it would be [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge seems a little bit overkill there, you can do it base `python` with list comprehension in one line:

```
l = ["ab", "ac", "bc", "ab", "ab", "abc"]
dic = {"ab" : 0, "ac" : 1, "bc" : 2, "abc" : 3,}

In [10]: [dic[el] for el in l]
Out[10]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
```

If you work with `Series`:

```
pd.Series([dic[el] for el in pd.Series(l)])
```